# Online Chat using two Browser windows at the same time

Tags: c#

Im a beginner in DotNet.Im doing a project on Online Education.In my project the trainers and trainee should be able to chat in online with two browser windows at the same time.How can I process over it?Please help me to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it has to be on your website and also confidential, but there is plenty of free chat widgets and services out there.. Why write another one? Some are even hosted elsewhere else, all you have to do is register. Some are widgets that you can embed in your own site:

[10 chat widgets to consider](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/10_chat_widgets.php) to name a few

Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you google "C# chat client server" you should get a lot of hits and samples.

If you are talking pure web then you would probably be saving the chat's into a table of some sort.  .Net allows you to automatically monitor changes to a database and then load the new information.  All you need to do then is implement a Data Repository using something like Linq-2-SQL, reload the chat window with the new data and you're essentially done.

You might want to investigate the microsoft mvc framework as this will allow you to render what they call partial views to your page using jQuery which would make the whole thing look seamless.

This is a bigger question than you think and I think you might want to consider some the the above ideas and then ask more pertinent questions.